# Single-line power transmission of 1MW over 35,000km

Tags: power, transmission-line, waveguide

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/426385/could-the-tether-of-a-space-elevator-be-used-as-a-single-wire-transmission-line) posted on the physics stack exchange has not received much attention. I thought the audience here might be more able to answer it.

## Background

A [space elevator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator) is mechanism to provide enormously lower cost access to orbit / space. While sounding fantastical, apparently there is real discussion and current investment in trying to develop some of the necessary technology for such a device.

The advantage of the device is that it avoids "the [tyranny of the rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation)". To achieve this though, it must be possible to send power to climbers ascending the elevator, rather than have them carry their own power source.

## Energy and power requirements.

Assuming a climber of 2 tons, wanting to achieve [geostationary orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_orbit) at `35,000 km`, the total energy to be delivered is `2,000 kg * 9.8 ms^-2 * 35,000,000 m ~ 700 GJ` (I'm using uniform `g`, making this an overestimate).

If the climb takes 7 days (approximately 200 km per hour), then the power requirement for the climber is about `1 MW`.

Current favoured solutions to this transmission are to use lasers to shine power to the climber, which would receive the power using photovoltaic panels. [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerlight_Technologies) an example.

## Question

A likely candidate material for the tether is [graphene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene), which is [an excellent conductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene#Electronic).

Given this, can ["single-line" power transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-wire_transmission_line) provide 1MW of power continuously over 35,000 km without adding undue bulk to the line or receiver?

## Notes on possible answers

The answer: *"No, this would almost certainly be highly impractical because …"* would be an excellent answer.

Some suggested points that an answer might address, and which might make the approach impractical:

- Radiative loss from the tether.
- Shape constraints on the tether to make it suitable for power transmission.
- Mass constraints on the tether due to insulation requirements.
- Mass constraints on the climber for receiver equipment.

Comment: I think questions involving phrases such as "is this possible" and talking about a theoretical device bordering on sci-fi may be a bit too broad for this site. This could be closed as either too broad or opinion-based as theoretical approaches will have many many different opinions on how to achieve such a feat with little or no real evidence to back them up

Comment: would the climber get more power for a given mass to carry from a wind turbine compared to solar panels, given the wind speeds in the upper atmosphere - assuming they get that high...

Comment: I am voting to close this question as "Too Broad", I do think that the practical implications of single-conductor power transmission might be worth exploring though (and a proper rephrasing of the question could accomplish that). I don't think focusing on that aspect of the question is opinion-based, as it is strictly a physics and wave propagation theoretical engineering exercise.

Comment: @SolarMike The proposed photovoltaic panels on the climber point down to the ground to pick up light directed at the climber from an array of lasers, rather than being directed to the sun. There's insufficient atmosphere for most of the climber's trip for wind power, or just a glider wing, to work.

Comment: I've clarified the question hoping it will be reopened. Without background, the question boils down to: can single-line power transmission practically deliver 1MW continuously over a 35,000 km line?

Comment: Given it did not get any response over on the Physics stack, perhaps it should stay closed...

Comment: Hi @SolarMike… I'm honestly unsure what that would mean :-) … Perhaps the idea is as infeasible as trying to power a kettle wireless in the manner a crystal radio works by scavenging EM radiation. But if that's the case, it seems to warrant a simple answer pointing out why this would be the case, such as "state of the art single-line power transmission provides at most milliwatts of power". Perhaps single-line power tx is not well understood – which is also fine. Or maybe the question is poor – I've tried to include references?

Comment: It is not unfeasible and could even be at least as practical as lasers and microwaves. But, for mostly cultural and historical reasons, most EEs would see it as voodoo and crazy talk. A comment section is not enough to expand on this, so I am nominating it for reopening.

Comment: @EdgarBrown Thank you – Is there a mechanism to petition for the question to be reopened, or to determine if the criticism still applies?

Comment: @Benjohn you can try asking those that voted to close or making the case for it to be reopened in Meta, that way you can get more guidance on how to rephrase. As I see it, it has had 2 reopen votes in three days (I believe it needs 5). As it ages, it seems unlikely to be reopened.

Comment: @Benjohn see here: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6874/202270

Comment: @EdgarBrown Many thanks for your input, by the way – it is much appreciated.

Comment: @Benjohn The solution is empirical test. This and Goubau microwave aren't textbook EE, while rf FEM code would suffer gigo, probably reveal no more than our biased speculations.Build the frickn' thing. Would high-amp contact shoes be a limit, would capacitive pickup work fine?  At 1MW, will its e-fields ignite glow-discharge during 200KM altitude, forming an RF mirror blocking propagation? (It burned NASA's tether!) Is optimum "catcher" enormously larger than crawler? Try and see. Let the experiment be made. Build 30ft mini hardware, mW or higher. Need a vac system? KW rf source? U R where?

Comment: @wbeaty :-) I think you are right, and I like your style. … unfortunately, I'd have little idea where to begin, beyond asking "is this likely to work at all?" on an a questions and answers site and hoping for "perhaps … and it might look like this" responses :-/

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the tether could be constructed to act as a microwave waveguide which can be tapped by the climber.

Comment: Sounds like a space ladder rather than a space elevator, but OK. Makes me tired just to think about it.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The hard bit is working out optimum tether dimensions,  frequency and precise tapping mechanism. Not to mention long line impedance etc. Two tethers are a LOT simpler

Comment: "Two tethers are a LOT simpler" - And may be required for mechanical redundancy anyway.

Comment: Single-conductor power transmission is in effect using a waveguide relying on the TM mode propagating outside of the conductor. It actually has lower losses and wider bandwidth than a standard (enclosed) waveguide.

Comment: @EdgarBrown Could you expand on this? In this case the requirement is to deliver the order of 1MW over a distance of 35,000 km, while not adding undue weight to the line or the receiver.